# Change line style in stat_quantiles if they are significative or not gplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, quantile, quantreg

I am making an analysis of covariance using quantiles and I would like to plot using `ggplot2` quantile lines by group but changing the style if they are significant at some level e.g. p<0.1

```
library(quantreg)
library(ggplot2)
data(barro)
barro$group=factor(round(runif(nrow(barro),1,3)))

fit0 <- rq(y.net ~  lgdp2 * group , data = barro,tau=c(.25, .5, .75))
sf <-summary(fit0,se="boot")

#extract coefficients
as.data.frame(lapply(sf, coef))

ggplot(barro,aes(lgdp2,y.net)) +facet_wrap( ~ group)+ geom_point(aes(colour=group)) +  theme_bw() + stat_quantile()
```

[image]

In this plot all lines have the same style and I don't figure out how to change the style of the quantile lines, to know which of them are significative at the specified p level.

Comment: What do you mean when you are calling a line "significant". That term generally refers to a parameter value comparison to a null value. (So I think you need to improve your understanding of statistical fundamentals before proceeding.)

Comment: Is this helpful `ggplot(barro, aes(lgdp2, y.net)) + geom_point(aes(colour=group)) + facet_wrap( ~ group) +  theme_bw() + stat_quantile() + stat_quantile(quantiles = 0.1, colour = "red")`?

Comment: @42 yes the null is that slopes are 0 and p-values are in the coefficients table like "Pr...t..." which means Pr(>|t|)

Comment: @EricFail that's a start but the quantiles=0.1 for all the groups are red, I want only the significant ones.